# How to use get and paginate same time in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to use paginate. I researched if I use paginate() I have to erase ->get().
but I got error. Could you teach me how to add paginate please?

my current code

```
$images = ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->get()->paginate(5);
        return view('image-gallery2',compact('images'));
```

blade file code

```
{{ $image->links() }}
```

*UPDATE*

if I do this

```
$images = ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->get()->paginate(5);
```

This error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

If I write below

```
$images = ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->paginate(5);
        return view('image-gallery2',compact('images'));
```

I got this error

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to undefined method App\ImageGallery::links() (View: //resources/views/image-gallery2.blade.php)
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `get()`, directly:

```
$images = ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->paginate(5);
```

in your blade you forgot the `s` for `$images`, the code is as follow:

```
{{ $images->links() }}
```

Comment: Dear @Christophe Hubert. Hi Sir you again. Thank you very much for answer I got this error.  what do I need ? Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: what about now, without the `->get()`?

Comment: I got this error now . Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to undefined method App\ImageGallery::links() (View: //resources/views/image-gallery2.blade.php)

Comment: Please add additional code in your question, not in comment - so it it easier to follow up 

Comment: please see the final answer and accept it if it solves your question 

Comment: Dear @Christophe Hubert Thank you very much. you saved me again! I apreciate!!!

Comment: You're very welcome! As usual, keep coding and feel free to ask us more 